# Loading library to my project crash my app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-library

i have a project using `fr.northborders.AnimationPlayground` to draw svg
when i add another library like `Android-Bootstrap`or `MaterialDesignLibrary` to project it will crash in runtime.

```
12-23 13:51:11.984: E/dalvikvm(4817): Could not find class 'fr.northborders.AnimationPlayground.FragmentAnimation.FragmentAnimationActivity', referenced from method fr.northborders.AnimationPlayground.Main.MainActivity.startDynamicForm
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817): FATAL EXCEPTION: main




12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fr.northborders.AnimationPlayground/fr.northborders.AnimationPlayground.DrawPathSvg.DrawPathSvgActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fr.northborders.AnimationPlayground.DrawPathSvg.SvgView
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fr.northborders.AnimationPlayground.DrawPathSvg.SvgView
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at fr.northborders.AnimationPlayground.DrawPathSvg.DrawPathSvgActivity.addSvgView(DrawPathSvgActivity.java:33)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at fr.northborders.AnimationPlayground.DrawPathSvg.DrawPathSvgActivity.onCreate(DrawPathSvgActivity.java:28)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1084)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     ... 11 more
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     ... 20 more
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817): Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: fr/northborders/AnimationPlayground/Utils/SvgHelper
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at fr.northborders.AnimationPlayground.DrawPathSvg.SvgView.<init>(SvgView.java:32)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     at fr.northborders.AnimationPlayground.DrawPathSvg.SvgView.<init>(SvgView.java:52)
12-23 13:51:20.879: E/AndroidRuntime(4817):     ... 23 more
```

Comment: did you add Android-Bootstrapor/MaterialDesignLibrary project as a library to your project

Comment: @ClintonDsouza Yes, the 'fr.northborders.AnimationPlayground' was AndroidStudio project wich i open in eclipse and without the library rans fine but the other library are eclipse project. now i tried another project from AS to eclipse  have same problem with library.also i tested library in new project they working fine. is that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after i tried a lot to fix this problem i figured out that the library `res` will not compile with project which i don't understand but i just merged all library projects together in new project (like copy all resource value drawable style and everything related).
now its work like a charm! :)